# OpenGL program doesn't show any picture

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I've tried to display a simple triangle, but nothing appears on screen.

I can clear the color but, nothing else.  (I've put averything in one big file).
I'm using SDL to create the window. Everything else should be just OpenGL.

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    // Init window
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);

    GLenum status = glewInit();

    if(status != GLEW_OK){
        std::cerr << "Glew failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    isClosed = false;

    // Init everything else

    GLuint vaoID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    GLuint vboID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    GLfloat vert2[] = {-1,-1,0, 1,-1,0, 0,0,0};
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vert2), vert2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    GLuint frag = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint vert = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    std::string sFrag = "#version 130 \n out vec4 out_color; \n void main(void){out_color = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1);}";
    std::string sVert = "#version 130 \n in vec3 pos; \n void main(void){gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1);}";
    char const* cFrag = sFrag.c_str();
    char const* cVert = sVert.c_str();

    GLint success = 0;
    glShaderSource(frag, 1, &cFrag, NULL);
    glCompileShader(frag);
    glGetShaderiv(frag, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(success == GL_FALSE) std::cerr << "Möb" << std::endl;
       else std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;

    glShaderSource(vert, 1, &cVert, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vert);
    glGetShaderiv(vert, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(success == GL_FALSE) std::cerr << "Möb" << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vert);
    glAttachShader(program, frag);
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "pos");
    glDeleteShader(vert);
    glDeleteShader(frag);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    //glValidateProgram(program);

    while(!isClosed){
        glUseProgram(program);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);



        // Update

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        SDL_Event e;

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
             if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
                  isClosed = true;
             }
       }

       glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your code, but none of them would necessary explain the issue. 1: You don't specify an GL version and profile, but you're using `#version 330 core` shaders. Depending on the GL implementaion you're using, this will or will not work. 2. You try to draw 4 vertices, but only 3 are in the buffer. 3. You never check the link status of your program. 4. You don;t check for any GL errors at all.

Comment: @derhass: Don't forget a completely absent `glewInit()` call.

Comment: I just forgot to copy it

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `glClear()` before `display.update()`, which seems to suggest you are clearing the back buffer before swapping it. Granted the other code is correct, if you swap the position of `glClear()` and `display.update()`, you may see something.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me. But after I swapped it, the result stayed the same.

Comment: It may be worth updating the question with what library you are using to create the GL context as well as whether you are basing the code on an example. (Some libraries require you to explicitly setup the extensions.) The next thing I would check is if it is creating a depth buffer. If that is the case, you should change glClear() to glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: I think, I have setted everything up correctly concerning SDL and I added `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` as you see. But I get still the same result.